When two discord users interact with two different buttons, why does the later view created replace the earlier view?
I believe this is the minimal reproducible code.
from discord.ui import View,Button
from discord.ext import commands
import discord
import asyncio

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.', intents=discord.Intents.all(), case_insensitive=True)
@client.command()

async def test(ctx):
    testclass = TestCog(ctx)
    await testclass.test()


class TestCog():
    
    def __init__(self, ctx):
        self.ctx = ctx

    async def test(self):

        view = TestView(self.ctx)
        message = await self.ctx.send(view=view)
        view.message = message
    

class TestView(View):
    def __init__(self, ctx):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)
        self.interaction_received = False
        self.ctx = ctx
        self.message = None
    
    @discord.ui.button(label="1", style=discord.ButtonStyle.success, custom_id= 'one')
    async def yes_button(self, interaction:discord.Interaction, button: Button):

        if interaction.user.id != self.ctx.author.id:
            await self.ctx.send(f"interaction id:{interaction.user.id} and uid:{self.ctx.author.id}")
            await self.ctx.send(f"{self.message.interaction_metadata}")
            return
        
        view = TestView2(self.ctx)
        ### POSSIBLE AREA OF INTEREST
        await interaction.response.send_message(view=view)
        ###################################################
        message = await interaction.original_response()
        view.message = message
        self.disable_buttons()
        await self.message.edit(view=self)
    
    def disable_buttons(self):
        for item in self.children:
            item.disabled = True


class TestView2(View):
    def __init__(self,ctx):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)
        self.interaction_received = False
        self.ctx = ctx
        self.message = None
    
    @discord.ui.button(label="2", style=discord.ButtonStyle.success, custom_id= 'two')
    async def yes_button(self, interaction:discord.Interaction, button: Button):
        if interaction.user.id != self.ctx.author.id:
            await self.ctx.send(f"interaction id:{interaction.user.id} and uid:{self.ctx.author.id}")
            await self.ctx.send(f"{self.message.interaction_metadata}")
            return
    
        view = TestView(self.ctx)
        await interaction.response.send_message(view=view)
        message = await interaction.original_response()
        view.message = message
        self.disable_buttons()
        await self.message.edit(view=self)
    
    def disable_buttons(self):
        for item in self.children:
            item.disabled = True

async def main():
    await client.start(BOTTOKEN)

asyncio.run(main())

Steps to reproduce bug (requires two users):

User1 types .test
User2 types .test
User1 presses their 1 button.
User2 presses their 1 button.
User1 can try to press their 2 button, but will find out they can't.

So I tried the "Steps to reproduce bug" above and I expected User1 is able to press their 2 button even after User2 presses their 1 button. What actually happened was that User1 was unable to press their 2 button.
NOTE: I know there is this snippet of code that makes sure the author is the same user interacting with the button.
if interaction.user.id != self.ctx.author.id:
    await self.ctx.send(f"interaction id:{interaction.user.id} and uid:{self.ctx.author.id}")
    await self.ctx.send(f"{self.message.interaction_metadata}")
    return

I know this stops the interaction, but the problem is either self.ctx.author.id is getting replaced, the interaction response object is the same so the second press of the 1 button is replacing the view of the first press of the 1 button, OR something else is going on.
SOLUTION:
I found the answer after reading Discord's doc on Message Components and custom_id.
https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/message-components
I just removed the custom_id of both buttons and the code works.
I also found out that if the @discord.ui.button() decorator doesn't have a custom_id then a unique custom_id will be generated.
